# Openlayers - How to get last drawn coordinate of a Polygon

Tags: openlayers

In Openlayers you are able to delete the last Point when drawing a Polygon. But I cannot find a way to just get the Point object. If it is possible to delete the last point it should also be possible to just get the last Point?

I have added a `change` listener to the feature that I am drawing then I log the `getLastCoordinate` method. But when I draw a new Point then this last coordinate does not change.

So the weird thing is that the `Draw` object when you are drawing a new Feature does have a method called `removeLastPoint` which removes the last Point that is drawn. If it is possible to do this, why is it not possible to just get the last Point.

```
      listener.value = feature.getGeometry().on('change', (evt) => {
        const geom = evt.target;
        console.log(geom.getLastCoordinate());
      });
```

Comment: A Polygon ring is closed so the last coordinate should always be the same as the first.  The last drawn coordinate will be the one before the last `geom.getCoordinates()[0].slice(-2)[0];`

Comment: @Mike Thanks for the answer! If I try out your solution. Then I always get the coordinates of the point where the mouse is at. In order to get the last Point that was drawn I use `geom.getCoordinates()[0].slice(-3)[0]`.

Comment: I think `getLastCoordinate()` for LineString will also gives the mouse position.  The last drawn point will be the previous coordinate.